# Hypotenuse of a rectangular pyramid

Tags: geometry

I am hoping someone will solve this problem (I could do it if it was a flat one but couldn't do it for the pyramid. Here is the question:

$1)$ Size of base of the rectangular pyramid= $45 \text{ ft} \times  52\mathrm' 6\mathrm"$

$2)$ Height at the center $=6 \text { ft}$

Could someone please show the process (step by step calculation) of working out the problem?

[image: rectangular pyramid]

Comment: By "hypotenuse" I suspect you mean the length of an edge connecting the apex of the pyramid to a corner of the base.  Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You can build on your experience with two dimensional lengths.

Notice that the "hypotenuse" to a corner of the base forms an "upward" right triangle with the "altitude" from the apex to the center of the base, with the third side being a half-diagonal of the rectangular base (drawn to the same corner from the center).

Now in your case the altitude (height) is known to have length 6 ft.  The half-diagonal of the base has (by using the Pythagorean Theorem to get the full diagonal) length of about 34.57 ft. (an irrational number, as it happens).

Using the Pythagorean Theorem (again) on the "upward" right triangle gives:

$$ \sqrt{6^2 + 34.57^2} \approx 35.09 \text{ feet} $$

as the length of its diagonal (which is your "hypotenuse").